# Yii2 Gridview error

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-basic-app, yii2-model

I want to display column from another table in gridview.

In my controller actionIndex:

```
public function actionIndex()
{     
    $user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    $queryFile = PowerGen::find();
    $queryFile ->select(['submitted_by','filename.file_name','filename.submitted_by'])
        ->joinWith('filename')//Tells Yii to use the complains relation that we define below. By default it is an inner join
        ->where(['filename.submitted_by' => $this->user_id]);

    $dataProvider= new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);

    return $this->render('index', ['dataProvider4'=>$dataProvider]);
}
```

In my model:

```
public function fileName()
{
    $user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    return $this->hasMany(Filename::className(), 'submitted_by' => $this->user_id);
}
```

Error is:

```
Error
PHP Parse Error – yii\base\ErrorException
syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)
```

What is the error in the line..

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Use [hasMany()](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#hasMany()-detail) like

```
public function fileName()
{
    $user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
    return $this->hasMany(Filename::className(), ['submitted_by' => $this->user_id]);
}
```

Comment: Oh, i see you added brackets. let me try

Comment: for "$this->user_id",  how can I tag the logged user?

Comment: Using `$this->user_id` in relation definition is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First i think your function must be like this:

```
public function fileName()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Filename::className(), ['submitted_by' => 'user_id']);
}
```

And your query like this:

```
$user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
$queryFile = PowerGen::find();
$queryFile ->select(['submitted_by','filename.file_name','filename.submitted_by'])
                ->joinWith('filename')
                ->where(['filename.submitted_by' => $user_id]);
```

You are declaring the variable `$user_id`

> $user_id = \Yii::$app->user->identity->id;

but you are not using it anywhere.

Comment: I need to display only the files submitted by the logged user.

Answer (score 0):

You're defining your relation in a wrong way:

1. Method name should be prefixed by `get`, like `getFileName()`.
2. Second argument of `hasMany()` should be array with map of column names. You should not use dynamic values here or model attributes.
3. You should not use `Yii::$app->user->identity->id` or POST/GET data in your model. It breaks MVC pattern and will create problems if you will try to use this relation in console for example.

```
public function getFileName() {
    return $this->hasMany(Filename::className(), ['submitted_by' => 'user_id']);
}
```

Comment: I need to display the files submitted by the logged user.

Comment: Then you should add this condition in controller. Model should not be responsible for such magic.